# How to remove rounded corners in Kali Linux (kali-rolling)

Tags: gnome, kali-linux, gnome-shell

In  **/usr/share/themes/my_custom_theme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css** I have:

```
@import url("/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css");

/* GLOBALS */

#panel .panel-corner,
#panel .panel-corner:focus,
#panel .panel-corner:active,
#panel .panel-corner:overview,
#panel .panel-corner.lock-screen,
#panel .panel-corner.login-screen,
#panel .panel-corner.unlock-screen {
    -panel-corner-border-width: 2px;
    -panel-corner-radius: 0px;
    -panel-corner-background-color: transparent;
    -panel-corner-border-width: 0px;
    -panel-corner-border-color: transparent; 
}
```

I'm trying to remove the rounded corners, but this doesn't seem to have any effect towards that end. What am I missing to make it work.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What corners should be round?

Comment: The file/ folder Explorer corners, if possible also all other windows, @pfnuesel